# Symbolic link to dir created inside docker container

Tags: docker, symlink

I wonder if anyone knows why this is happening?
When I create a symbolic link inside a docker container (the container shell, not a dockerfile) like this...

```
ln -s "/foo/bar/dir.pack" /path
```

The resulting link is an "archive" (red) according to `ls` and I cant `cd` into it.

The links I am trying to make are inside -v mounted directories.
I can create the links on the host and they work as intended, but if I try making them inside the container I get this weird behaviour.

What might I be doing wrong?

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]; what is the complete Dockerfile (including this `RUN ln -s` command) and what directories are you mounting where?  (You'll probably lose work if you try to manipulate the container filesystem in an interactive shell.)

Comment: This is not in a dockerfile, this is inside a running container. The links I am trying to make are from one part of a mounted volume to another part of a mounted volume. Since the volume is mounted from the host, I can create the link on the host, easy, no problems. But trying to run the same command (with paths changed to suit mount) inside the docker container behaves as described (links show as archives, not directories).

Comment: Processing the symbolic link is context dependent; if you `cd /path` in your example then you'll go to `/foo/bar/dir.pack`, but this will probably be a different location inside the container and outside because of `docker run -v` filesystem remapping.  Without being able to see these details it's hard to diagnose this further.